# Should I store long text in the column (text type) or in the file?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, file, cloud-storage

I have created cloud storage service which allow you to create files and write texts and save it like dropbox. But problem is if text is long it cant store it in the one column,there are 2 solutions:

**1**)I should separate texts and save it in different columns which a little bit messy

**2**)I should save texts in the real files

Which one is more efficient? What about Google drive and Dropbox? How do they handle that?

Comment: I would guess that drive and dropbox have some fairly complex caching mechanisms that would most likely be overengineering for a smaller-scale application.

Comment: I thing `google drive and dropbox` arent limit to save any type of text into the database. Can you switch to `BLOB` or `MEDIUMTEXT`? And why is 65,000 length (`TEXT` max size) not enuff?

Comment: create a new table with a unique key and a text field. so your query to find the blob is quicker and join the new table

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions yes I am able to choose them, but I dont know bad effect of blob, and which one is best blob or file ?

Comment: @BerndBuffen Why not use file sistem?what is the disadvantage of each one?

Comment: @Bucky - it is a very hard work to hold consistent. There is no "normal" way for Tansactions over both storage systems.  and you cant easy find out if one file is missed. And its also difficult to store them in a structure. Lets say you store all files from a user in one directory and you have 100000 user so you have one folder with 100000 subdirs. also the answer from CollinD

Comment: @CollinD Okay which way is better for begining file system or blob ?

Comment: @BerndBuffen I have created system which allow users to create folder but all these folder is in the database with a some logic and not real folder for my server.Only problem is text files inside,which way is better for begining?Or what about create a system which detect if text is long it begins to seperate text to different columns?